# How to change height and width of input fields according to specific position of page in html?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have this picture as a background of my html page.

I want to put input text fields on that part of image where textfields exist. I want to change the height and width of the input fields according to the fields in picture, because I've made background image responsive.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can Give size to Text-field by...

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" style="height:30px;width:30px">
```

But for setting the position you need to use css

```
#id_name{
position:absolute;
// also can give  style(height and width) here...
//margin and padding as per you requirement.
}
```

Here you can use Class selector , Id selector , or tag selector any of them.